# Why is Bluetooth Using Cellular Data when it is turned off?

Tags: bluetooth, cellular

I reset the Cellular data statistics on my iPhone 6 yesterday and went to Settings > Cellular > System Services. I noticed that Bluetooth had used 3.3 KB of Cellular data. A few hours later, I noticed it had used 3.5 KB of data. While this isn't a lot, why is Bluetooth using any at all? If Bluetooth is off, shouldn't it be using no Cellular data at all?

Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Bluetooth itself is a short range communication protocol and shouldn't use cellular data. An app connected to something else by BT might use data. Can you post a screen shot of your usage?